# MySql group by and include null

Tags: mysql

I have these 2 tables:

```
Table members
| id | name    |
----------------
| 01 | John    |
| 02 | Michael |
| 03 | Richard |
```

and

```
Table payments
| id  | eur  | name    | date       |
-------------------------------------
| 238 | 9.95 | John    | 1323377751 |
| 233 | 9.95 | Michael | 1397864609 |
| 220 | 9.95 | Michael | 1397852739 |
| 215 | 9.95 | John    | 1397852719 |
|   2 | 9.95 | Richard | 1323377751 | // This payment was made more than 24h ago
```

Bellow is my query:

```
select id, m.name, sum(eur) as total 
from mambers as m
left join payments as p
on m.name = p.name
where p.date >= unix_timestamp(current_timestamp - interval 24 hour)
group by m.name
```

and the return is:

```
| John    | 19.90 |
| Michael | 19.90 |
```

but i need to include also the members with no payments in last 24 like this:

```
| John    | 19.90 |
| Michael | 19.90 |
| Richard | 00.00 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two errors occurred while trying your query.

1. table name `mambers` does not exist.
2. Ambiguous column name `id`.

Try this instead:

```
select m.id, m.name, IFNULL(sum(eur),'00.00') as total 
from members as m
left join payments as p
on m.name = p.name and p.date >= unix_timestamp(current_timestamp - interval 24 hour)
group by m.name
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME      TOTAL
1   John      10
2   Michael   20
3   Richard   00.00
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f636/3).

Comment: @V.Donchev: Edited my answer. Now its working. You can check the sample result in fiddle.